# image scaling using hanning windows function

Tags: c++, image-processing

i have an assignment to scale an image and apply hanning windows function to it.
image is of pgm type. black and white (grayscale) with pixel value ranging from 0 to 255.

i have read various articles on hanning function.

from wikipedia:

```
w(n) = 0.5*(1 - cos(2*pi*n)/(N-1))
```

for 0<=n<=(N-1)

where n is the input, N is the width of the window.

the values for N i am allowed to use are 0-9.

My question is that how can i use such values for N when the n (input) has to be lower than it. n(input) is going to be pixel values (0 to 255)

am i using the wrong function?
i am applying this function for all pixel values and storing it in a new image. all i am getting is a completely black image as output.

EDIT - adding partial code

```
for (int i = 0; i < OUTlen; i++) 
{
        OUT[i] = 0.5(1 - cos(2*PI*IN[i]/(N-1));
}
```

OUT is the array that stores pixels for new image(output)
IN is the array that stores pixel values for the original image on which  hanning has to be applied
PI is 3.14159265359
N is the width of the window, tried 0-9 values for N as instructed by the teacher. also tried 256 as value for N because pixel values range from 0-256

EDIT2 - changing code to reflect comments
changed code to this

```
for (int i = 0; i < OUTlen; i++) 
{
        OUT[i] = IN[i]*(0.5*(1 - cos(2*PI*IN[i]/(N-1)));
}
```

now multiplying pixel values as well. still black output

Comment: Show us what code you have so far please.

Comment: edited. its basically the wiki formula turned into c++ code

Comment: Well, `cos()` of anything will return a value on range [0-1], so `1-cos(anything)` will also be on range [0-1], so when you multiply that by 0.5, you will be on range [0-0.5] which will amount to black. Maybe try multiplying your result by 255, at least, to get a bigger number..

Comment: A Hanning window will give you values between 0 and 1 - these are then used to multiply the pixel intensity values. I think your confusion is because N is the width of the Hanning window and *n* is a number from 0 to N-1 indicating the position of that coefficient.

Comment: @Roger Rowland 
i get that N is the width
i thought n is the pixel value i need to input, is that not it? 
now multiplying pixel values as well. still black output

Comment: The idea of windowing is to gradually darken the image at the edges. So you multiply the pixel values by a number that varies from 0 to 1 as you move in from the edge. The distance from the edge is what the *n* is effectively representing - it will vary from 0 to 1 and back to 0 over the window width of N.

Comment: hmm
@RogerRowland
i used one formula that gave a result to what you are saying. but my teacher said that it was not an expected output of hanning function

please check this image and let me know that after applying scaling and hanning function to the image on the right if the image on the left is the expected output
http://tinypic.com/r/durn5/8

Comment: Well it looks like a Hanning window (or some similar window) has been applied ok, not sure why your teacher says its not expected. Normally this technique is used in preparation for working in the frequency domain, so if that's not where you're heading it might be best to ask your teacher to clarify the assignment. From what you described, and what you've done, it looks ok to me (but then I'm not the one teaching you) ;-)

Comment: @RogerRowland
we were told to use image scaling on the give image and then apply filters.
nearest neighbor, linear interpolation, and cubic convolution, Hann, Hamming, and Lanczos windows
she says my hanning and hamming outputs are not correct.
not giving explanation on whats wrong
but according to you this is expected right?

Comment: Then you'd better ask her what she's expecting - apart from the fact that the width of the window may be incorrect, I can't guess what she wants. Re-edit your question if we've been heading the wrong way and you still can't figure it out.